# select link with a specific get param

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to select a link which have a specific get param
in the example below the first link should be selected
any help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let a = 'lorem';
  //$('.navb[having c = a]').addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.act{
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='navb' href='index.php?c=lorem'>abc</a>
<a class='navb' href='index.php?c=ipsum'>def</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let a = 'c=lorem';
  $(".navb[href*='"+a+"']").addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.act{
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='navb' href='index.php?c=lorem'>abc</a>
<a class='navb' href='index.php?c=ipsum'>def</a>
```

Comment: @qadenza, you are most welcome, updated the answer with more accurate solution using *Attribute Contains Selector*:)